# how to rotate view circular with rotategesture

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

[image]In my app as shown in figure I need to rotate the view circular as shown in figures. how can i set that.

green is nbutton and red is nview. my code is :

```
func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer)
    {

            nView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageViews[i].transform, recognizer.rotation)
            nButton.center = CGPointMake((nView.frame.origin.x), (nView.frame.origin.y))
            recognizer.rotation = 0
}
```

[image]

Actually I am enable to get the frame of imageView here. Even bounds not working for me..

Comment: so basically your question is how to get frame of UIImageView?

Comment: yes.. Exactly.. But when I am using imageView.frame is not working

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? is it giving any error ? or you are getting some unexpected result ?

Comment: no its not giving me proper frame like shown in figure some times if image is straight it is showing me proper but when i rotate it it inclined

Comment: I think you are facing this because of anchor points. Please search about anchor points

Comment: Ok.. I am searching..

Comment: So, You want me to deal with layer??